# Inserting multple rows into table from a submit form

Tags: php, mysql

Please I want to know the possibility of successfully executing the below code...
Please if its possible to implement, can someone help me and put me through where I'm getting it wrong.

...think I'm a green horn here

```html
<!---HTML file--->
<form name='myform' action='test.php' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='fname' value='John' />
<input type='text' name='phone' value='+254 ********' />

<input type='text' name='fname' value='Jane' />
<input type='text' name='phone' value='+254 ********' />

<input type='text' name='fname' value='Chris' />
<input type='text' name='phone' value='+254 *********' />

<input type='text' name='fname' value='Solo' />
<input type='text' name='phone' value='+254 *********' />


<input type='submit'  value='I wish to insert all the four sets of records at once' />
</form>
```

```
$fname = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["fname"]));

$phone = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["phone"]));

$results = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (id, fname, phone)

VALUES 
 ('', '$fname', '$phone'),
 ('', '$fname', '$phone'),
 ('', '$fname', '$phone'),
 ('', '$fname', '$phone')");
```

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials on the internet, even on this site. Do a search "Quick start PHP Mysql Tutorial"

Answer (score 0):

Declare all the input name as array such as

```
  <input type='text' name='fname[]' value='John' />
   <input type='text' name='phone[]' value='+254           ********'    />
```

In Php file we can use for loop for get all the fname, phone